# How to convert hex chars to normal chars?

Tags: text-processing, character-encoding

I tried, but I'm stuck at "escaping" the "sed's":

```
sed -i 's/\\x0/NUL/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x1/SOH/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x2/STX/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x3/ETX/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x4/EOT/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x5/ENQ/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x6/ACK/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x7/BEL/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x8/BS/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x9/HT/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x0A/LF/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x0B/VT/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x0C/FF/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x0D/CR/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x0E/SO/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x0F/SI/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x10/DLE/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x11/DC1/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x12/DC2/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x13/DC3/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x14/DC4/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x15/NAK/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x16/SYN/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x17/ETB/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x18/CAN/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x19/EM/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x1A/SUB/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x1B/ESC/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x1C/FS/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x1D/GS/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x1E/RS/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x1F/US/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x20//g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x21/!/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x22/"/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x23/#/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x24/$/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x25/%/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x26/&/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x27'/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x28/(/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x29/)/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x2A/*/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x2B/0/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x2C/,/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x2D/0/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x2E/0/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x2F///g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x30/0/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x31/1/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x32/2/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x33/3/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x34/4/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x35/5/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x36/6/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x37/7/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x38/8/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x39/9/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x3A/:/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x3B/;/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x3C/</g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x3D/=/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x3E/>/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x3F/?/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x40/@/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x41/A/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x42/B/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x43/C/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x44/D/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x45/E/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x46/F/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x47/G/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x48/H/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x49/I/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x4A/J/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x4B/K/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x4C/L/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x4D/M/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x4E/N/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x4F/O/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x50/P/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x51/Q/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x52/R/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x53/S/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x54/T/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x55/U/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x56/V/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x57/W/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x58/X/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x59/Y/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x5A/Z/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x5B/[/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x5C/\/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x5D/]/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x5E/^/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x5F/_/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x60/`/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x61/a/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x62/b/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x63/c/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x64/d/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x65/e/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x66/f/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x67/g/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x68/h/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x69/i/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x6A/j/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x6B/k/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x6C/l/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x6D/m/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x6E/n/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x6F/o/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x70/p/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x71/q/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x72/r/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x73/s/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x74/t/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x75/u/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x76/v/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x77/w/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x78/x/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x79/y/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x7A/z/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x7B/{/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x7C/|/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x7D/}/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x7E/~/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x7F//g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x80/€/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x81//g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x82/‚/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x83/ƒ/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x84/„/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x85/…/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x86/†/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x87/‡/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x88/ˆ/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x89/‰/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x8A/Š/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x8B/‹/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x8C/Œ/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x8D//g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x8E/Ž/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x8F//g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x90//g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x91/‘/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x92/’/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x93/“/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x94/”/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x95/•/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x96/–/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x97/—/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x98/˜/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x99/™/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x9A/š/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x9B/›/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x9C/œ/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x9D//g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x9E/ž/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\x9F/Ÿ/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xA0//g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xA1/¡/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xA2/¢/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xA3/£/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xA4/¤/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xA5/¥/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xA6/¦/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xA7/§/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xA8/¨/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xA9/©/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xAA/ª/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xAB/«/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xAC/¬/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xAD//g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xAE/®/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xAF/¯/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xB0/°/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xB1/±/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xB2/²/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xB3/³/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xB4/´/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xB5/µ/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xB6/¶/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xB7/·/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xB8/¸/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xB9/¹/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xBA/º/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xBB/»/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xBC/¼/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xBD/½/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xBE/¾/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xBF/¿/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xC0/À/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xC1/A/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xC2/Â/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xC3/Ã/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xC4/Ä/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xC5/Å/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xC6/Æ/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xC7/Ç/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xC8/È/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xC9/E/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xCA/Ê/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xCB/Ë/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xCC/Ì/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xCD/I/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xCE/Î/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xCF/Ï/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xD0/Ð/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xD1/Ñ/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xD2/Ò/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xD3/O/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xD4/Ô/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xD5/Õ/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xD6/O/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xD7/×/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xD8/Ø/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xD9/Ù/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xDA/U/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xDB/Û/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xDC/U/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xDD/Ý/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xDE/Þ/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xDF/ß/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xE0/à/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xE1/a/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xE2/â/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xE3/ã/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xE4/ä/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xE5/å/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xE6/æ/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xE7/ç/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xE8/è/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xE9/e/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xEA/ê/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xEB/ë/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xEC/ì/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xED/i/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xEE/î/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xEF/ï/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xF0/ð/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xF1/ñ/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xF2/ò/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xF3/o/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xF4/ô/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xF5/õ/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xF6/o/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xF7/÷/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xF8/ø/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xF9/ù/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xFA/u/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xFB/û/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xFC/u/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xFD/ý/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xFE/þ/g' $1
sed -i 's/\\xFF/\ÿ/g' $1
```

How can I create a hex-code TO normal char converter? So that if I run:

```
sh thementionedscript.sh hexstrings.txt
```

-->> all the HEX chars in hexstrings.txt should be converted to normal chars, like: before:

```
\x68\x69
```

after:

```
hi
```

Comment: By the way, your example script is converting from \xXX to an encoding which is not the normal UTF-8, as there is no such thing as a single byte UTF-8 character > \x7F... If this is what you are actually after, then the current answers work only if the locale is appropriately set.... It looks like you want a conversion to Windows-1252 Character Encoding

Answer (score 4):

In `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf "$line"
done
```

`IFS=` is needed to stop IFS stripping occurring, that is, in most cases (where IFS contains whitespace, which is the norm) if you don't make IFS empty, whitespace will be stripped from each side of `"${line}"` regardless of the fact that you have quoted it. The `-r` option to read stops backspace interpretation.

Bear in mind that this will also interpret other escape codes which may be present in your source. If this concerns you, read the file character by character and only have printf act on \x escape codes.

You should *always* use a tempfile, so run it like this:

```
./foo < myfile > mytempfile && mv mytempfile myfile
```

Also, do not use `sed -i` to edit files, it is not portable, and even where it is the syntax varies between implementations (your code will fail on Mac OSX and most BSDs, for example). `ed` is the better option to edit files.

Comment: What? You're back too? Time for me to have a break then...

Comment: Oh come on, who uses `ed`? It's just *too* magic ;P

Comment: `ed` is POSIX, so it's far superior to other non-POSIX methods. And I use it, it still has one friend left ;)

Comment: +1 from me.  ["ed, man! !man ed"](http://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed.msg.html) FTW.

Comment: Ah, Darn you both. I'll learn it.

Answer (score 2):

In bash?

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read line
 do
 echo -e "$line"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a new take on the question...

To use `sed` to make the changes, you are 97% of the way there.
Here are some essential and some optional points to get it to work.

- It may be useful to make all you patterns case insensitive. 
  Use `ig` instead of `g`
- You can make all replacements in one pass. Simply concatenate them, eg. `'s/\\x00/NUL/ig;s/\\x01/SOH/ig;s/\\x02/STX/ig;...'`,
  or
  `'s/\\x01/SOH/ig; 

    s/\\x02/STX/ig; 

    ... 

      s/\\xFE/þ/ig; 

      s/\\xFF/ÿ/ig;'`
- You need to change some of the replacement expressions:
  `/'/` should be `/\x27/`     It clashes with the quoting `'` in 's/a/b/ig'
  `/\/` should be `/\\/`        Otherwise it escapes the `/`
  `/&/` should be `/\&/`        As on its own, it is a backreference
- You need to switch the `/` delimiter when `/` occurrs in your replacement expression.. Just for this one expression, change it to `|` (or whatever takes your fancy), eg. `s|\\x2F|/|g;`   Some sed situations require that it be escaped at the start of a pattern, eg. a range expression. `'\|^abc|q'`
- I've noticed a few differences in your list compared to what I came up with (based on the encoding being Windows-1252). You may like to check these: `7F`('DEL')   `A0`(' ')   `AD`('SHY')
- I encounter varying reports on the way `sed -i` handles so-called insitu updates. It  uses a temp file in any case, so I lean towards using `sponge` (package `moreutils`) for rewriting the  text file..

That's about it. Here is an example of the  resulting sed command...

```
 sed -e '
 s/\\x01/SOH/ig;
 s/\\x02/STX/ig;
 ...
 s/\\xFE/þ/ig;
 s/\\xFF/ÿ/ig;
 ' "$1" | sponge "$1"
```

The full command can be found at [paste.ubuntu](http://paste.ubuntu.com/717248/)

Comment: `sponge` isn't standard (I'd never heard the term in some 25 years of Unix, in fact).

Comment: `sponge` appears to be a "safe" wrapper for overwriting a file that is used as input earlier in a pipe. Such as `grep -v remove input | sponge input` instead of `grep -v remove input > input` which could truncate `input` before it has been read by grep. Part of "moreutils" (which I've never heard of before, too).

Answer (score 0):

*UPDATE* If you want to interpret the hex values as `Windows-1252` and represent them in your current locale's encoding (typically UTF-8 for *nix), you can use the following command. Note. That aside from the newlines (\n)  for each input line, this snippet takes as input *only* data in the form `\x33\x66\x99\xBB\xFF`... anything else causes an error.

```
<file sed -re 's|(.)\\x|\1,0x|g; s|^\\x|0x|; $!{s|$|,0x0a|}' |
 tr '\n' ',' | recode Windows-1252/x1..UTF-8
```

---

From here on, is my original answer (which doesn't consider diferent encodings)

You can use `xxd` in revert (-r) postscript (-p) mode. `xxd` is part of the `vi` package.
Note. The test data contains hexed \n (\x0a) chars.
`xxd` ignores any real \n chars, so you split the hex data over as many lines you wish (as in the test file).

`xxd` is also useful for converting a straight hexdump, eg. `68656c6c6f20776f726c64` (hello world)... *sed* is used in this example purely to remove the `\x'.

This first snippet ignores chars which are not in \xXX format...

```
<file sed -e 's|\\x||g' | xxd -p -r
```

If you want to keep the newlines (\n vs \x0a) from the souce file, use this (other text is ignored)

```
<file sed -e 's|\\x||g; s|$|0a|' | xxd -p -r
```

create a test file

```
echo -n "
\x63\x61\x74\x0a\x64\x6f\x67\x0a\x62\x69\x72\x64\x0a\x6d\x6f\x6f
\x73\x65\x0a\x61\x6c\x62\x61\x74\x72\x6f\x73\x73" >file
```

output (from 1st snippet, which only acts on \xXX data)

```
cat
dog
bird
moose
albatross
```

Comment: Bear in mind that this won't work with most standard files that aren't just a bunch of hex. Take the following as an example: the raw file `i would like a \x63\x61\x74\x0a or maybe a \x64\x6f\x67\x0a` would have no output.

Comment: ?? That is exactly what it does. Have you tested it? The test file contains exactly what is shown in the `echo` statement.. or do you mean it won't keep the newlines in the source file? ... that's a good point if that's what you mean..  (easily fixed. ammended answer)..

Comment: *@Chris:* I finally got your meaning (I was bleary eyed when I first looked at it)... yes, thanks, I was aware of that, but as the question has no reference to anything other than \xXX , I posted this answer, as it is a pretty simple way to convert without a loop..

Comment: I read the OP as referring to content which contained hex character codes, but not necessarily in full.